# Does looping through an enum create new objects?

Tags: java, android, enums

In my Android game I am looping through an enum like this multiple frames per frame:

```
for (IngameButton button : IngameButton.values()) {
    // some code
}
```

The memory allocation tracker shows that I am creating lots of Object Arrays (`Object[]`)

Does looping through an enum like that instantiate each enum like a class?